# How to set executor number by memory in YARN mode?

Tags: apache-spark

I did some testing on r3.8 xlarge cluster, each instance has 32 cores, and **244G memory**.

If I set spark.executor.cores=16, spark.executor.memory=**94G**, there're 2 executors per instance, but when I set spark.executor.memory larger than 94G, there will be only one executor per instance;

If I set spark.executor.cores=8, spark.executor.memory=**35G**, there're 4 executors per instance, but when I set spark.executor.memory larger than 35, there will be no larger than 3 executors per instance.

So, my question is, how does the executor number come out by memory set? What's the formula? I though the Spark just simply use 70% of the physical memory to allocate to the executors but seems I'm wrong...

Answer (score 0):

In Yarn mode you need to set number of executor by num-executors and executor memory by executor-memory. Here's a example:

```
spark-submit --master yarn-cluster --executor-memory 6G --num-executors 31 --executor-cores 32 example.jar Example
```

Now each executor requests a container from yarn with 6G + memory overhead and 1 core.

More info [on spark documentation](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/submitting-applications.html)

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the behavior you're seeing it sounds like the amount of memory available to your YARN NodeManagers is actually less than the 244GB that is available to the OS. To verify this, take a look at your YARN ResourceManager Web UI and you can see how much memory is availible in total across the cluster. This is determined from the `yarn.nodemanager.resource.memory-mb` in yarn-site.xml.

To answer your question about how the number of executors is determined: In YARN, if you're using spark with `dynamicAllocation.enabled` set to true, the number of executors is limited above `dynamicAllocation.minExecutors` and below `dynamicAllocation.maxExecutors`.

Other than that you're then subjected to YARN's resource allocation which, for most schedulers, will allocate resources to fill up a given queue that your job runs in.

In the situation where you have a totally unutilized cluster with one YARN queue and you submit a job to it, the Spark job will continue to add executors with the given number of cores and memory amount until the entire cluster is full (or there is not enough cores/memory for an additional executor to be allocated).